# dynamic number of columns in listview

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create a layout like this (Like Windows Tiles).

[image]

The number of columns will be 1 or 2.

Which layout I can use in android? I used ListView but in this I can't get two clickable columns. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html

Try using gridview

Answer (score 1):

Using the `ListView`. Implement your own `adapter` en create 2 xml layoutfiles. 1 with a layout that contains 1 frame, and another one that contains 2 frames. Just assign the correct type of layout based on your data.

Example:

1 frame:

```
<LinearLayout.. >
<!-- controls go here -->
</LinearLayout>
```

2 frames:

```
<LinearLayout.. > <!-- set to orientation to horizontal-->
<LinearLayout .. layout_weight="0.5" ><!-- controls go here --></LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout .. layout_weight="0.5" ><!-- controls go here --></LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Cool. I got the layout. But how I can make it seperately clickable by column? Right now clicking on it selects entire row.

Comment: Make sure you set on a onClickListener on the correct layouts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ListView` without problems, just that you need to make two separate items in xml, one that has two columns and one that has only one. You can add then click listener in your `ListView` Adapter while you are creating the items in `getView()`.